# Can't get the right bar button item on a navigation bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationitem

I'm trying to have a button on the right side of my navigation controller - after this works I'd like the button to be as near to invisible as possible while still working. Maybe setting to high transparency or changing the colour to the navigation bar colour (whatever is cheaper for memory).

First though I can't seem to get a visible or working button on the right side of my navigation bar:

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = 
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"coin" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
target:self action:@selector(changeToInAppScene:)];
```

Answer (score 16):

You have to assign to `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` (the navigation item of the current view controller), not `self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` .

Comment: Also make sure you do that after `viewDidLoad` gets called

Comment: viewDidLoad os going to be the death of me I swear, thank you so much :)!

Comment: @Caroline: You can accept only answers, not comments. But you can ask Tobi to provide his comment as an answer and then accept that!

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIBarButtonItem *rightBar = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Coin" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(changeToInAppScene:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBar;
}
```